# Unexpected Result with MAP

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was expecting the code under header 'New List with MAP' below to return a list just like the for loop and the list comprehension....but alas, it does not.  I get, `<map object at 0X000...8C1CD30>` instead.  How do i go from this to my list?

**New List with Map**

```
list_a = ['one_A', 'two_A', 'three_A']

#initialize the list
new_li = map(lambda i: '{0}\n'.format(i), list_a)

print(new_li)
```

**New List With Loop** (Works)

```
list_a = ['one_A', 'two_A', 'three_A']
new_li = []
for i in list_a:
    new_li.append('{i}\n'.format(i))

print(new_li)
```

**New List with List Comprehension** (Works)

```
list_a = ['one_A', 'two_A', 'three_A']

new_li = ['{i}\n'.format(i=i) for i in list_a]

print(new_li)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns an iterator. If you want the values in a list, you have to convert it to a list:

```
new_li = list(map(lambda i: '{0}\n'.format(i), list_a))
```

or

```
new_li = list(map('{0}\n'.format, list_a))
```

Comment: well that was easy, thanks!!  I'll accept your answer in 10 mins.